# Чтение из файла

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, скажите, вот у меня есть file1.txt, внутри есть 3 строки

```
привет
пока
как дела?
```

И вот есть в C# класс StreamReader, он может считать **ВСЕ** 3 строки, а вот если я, к примеру, хочу 2 строка 3-й символ, как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно поможет статический класс **[File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)**, у которого есть метод `ReadLines`

```
File.ReadLines(@"path\to\file1.txt").ToList()[1][2]// вернёт нужный вам символ
```

Comment: Ура! Спасибо, нашёл то что искал!

Comment: <Шаблонный комментарий>
Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).
</Шаблонный комментарий>

Comment: Да а ещё вопрос, а если я хочу прочитать к примеру от 1 **до** 5 символа 2-й строки?

Comment: методы ``Take()`` и ``Skip()``:

    File.ReadLines(@"path\to\file1.txt").ToList()[1].Skip(1).Take(4)

отбрасываем нулевой и считываем с 1 по 5

Comment: Хм... странно код

    File.ReadLines(@"path\to\file1.txt").ToList()[1][2]// вернёт нужный вам символ

не работает

>`Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement C:\Documents and Settings\Администратор\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 13 13 ConsoleApplication1`

Comment: а вы его чему-нибудь присвоили?

Comment: Нет просто в пустом проекте в Консоли попробовал.

Comment: Поэтому не работает. Обращение к свойству или индексатору должно быть куда-нибудь присвоено.

P.S. С точки зрения использования ресурсов, предложенный ответ - это просто издевательство над машиной.

Comment: не отрицаю, просто я хотел использовать индексы, т.к. они более наглядны.

Answer (score 3):

Вызывайте `StreamReader.ReadLine` столько раз, сколько Вам нужно пропустить строк. Последний вызов верёт вам нужную строку. Из неё с помощью индексатора прочитайте нужный символ.

Если уж использовать `File.ReadLines`, то вместо `ToList` нужно использовать `Skip`.